# Emacs issue: automatic repeated character insertion when use `TAB` key

Tags: emacs

Whenever I try to open a file or create a file in emacs on the typing tab a character keeps on getting typed automatically. Something like:

[image]

It also happens on first opening a file. A character keeps on getting typed infinitely unless I stop it manually. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you try running `emacs -q` and see if this behaviour persists? This will run emacs without any configuration or packages being loaded.

Comment: It still persists :(

Comment: Try also `emacs -Q`. If you still see the problem then it sounds like something outside Emacs might be interfering with `TAB`. What does `C-h k` followed by hitting `TAB` tell you. If you don't see a description pop up in buffer `*Help*`, and the prompt to hit a key doesn't go away, then Emacs is not even seeing your `TAB` key - something else is grabbing it.

Comment: Are you sure it's only with Emacs? And have you tried with a different keyboard?

Comment: That screenshot seems to show the GTK file picker. Does it also happen in other applications? I feel this may not be related to emacs itself. If it is emacs related, it would help to know what version and OS you are running.

Comment: The problem got resolved after a restart. Thanks for your opinions though.